YOLOv10 Training Shows YOLOv8 Version in Terminal - Why
I am training a custom dataset using YOLOv10 with the following command:
yolo task=detect mode=train epochs=100 batch=16 plots=True model=C:/Users/joker/Desktop/AS/weights/yolov10s.pt data=./tld_db/data.yaml

However, in the terminal, I see the following message:
Ultralytics YOLOv8.1.34  Python-3.12.4 torch-2.4.0+cu118 CUDA:0 (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Ti, 8192MiB)

Why does it say "v8.1.34"? Am I actually using YOLOv10?
Is it because I haven't uninstalled YOLOv8?

the number that you see here is version of your ultralytics if you want to check the model that you are using for training you should look for this line below in the terminal output. for example this is the output for my training:
engine/trainer: task=segment, mode=train, model=yolov8n-seg.pt, ...

it should be right after the line that says: Ultralytics YOLOv8.1.34  Python-3.12.4 torch-2.4.0+cu118 CUDA:0 (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Ti, 8192MiB)
check the model arg in this engine/trainer line
